# Skip/remove non-ascii character with sed

Tags: sed

> Chip,Dirkland,DrobæSphere Inc,cdirkland@hotmail.com,usa

I've been trying to use sed to modify email addresses in a .csv but the line above keeps tripping me up, using commands like:

```
sed -i 's/[\d128-\d255]//' FILENAME
```

[from this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337936/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-csv)

doesn't seem to work as I get an 'invalid collation character' error.

Ideally I don't want to change that combined AE character at all, I'd rather sed just skip right over it as I'm not trying to manipulate that text but rather the email addresses. As long as that AE is in there though it causes my sed substitution to fail after one line, delete the character and it processes the whole file fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
echo "Chip,Dirkland,DrobæSphere Inc,cdirkland@hotmail.com,usa" |
sed 's/\o346/a+e/g'
Chip,Dirkland,Droba+eSphere Inc,cdirkland@hotmail.com,usa
```

Then do what you have to do and after to revert do:

```
echo "Chip,Dirkland,Droba+eSphere Inc,cdirkland@hotmail.com,usa" | 
sed 's/a+e/\o346/g'
Chip,Dirkland,DrobæSphere Inc,cdirkland@hotmail.com,usa
```

If you have tricky characters in strings and want to understand how `sed` sees them use the `l0` command (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-g_t_0040value_007bSSEDEXT_007d_002c-setting-line-length-144)). Also very useful for debugging difficult regexps.

```
echo "Chip,Dirkland,DrobæSphere Inc,cdirkland@hotmail.com,usa" | 
sed -n 'l0'
Chip,Dirkland,Drob\346Sphere Inc,cdirkland@hotmail.com,usa$
```

Comment: +1 for the `l0`. There is another `sedsed.py` script too, available [here](http://aurelio.net/sedsed/). Useful to inspect `pattern` and `hold` spaces. Might not help in this case but a useful debugging tool none the less. :)

Comment: that sed -n 'l0' command is interesting, what it prints out for company is: Drob\357\277\275Sphere Inc

Comment: and I still can't get the examples above to work with it, perhaps the character (which shows as an AE in Windows LibreOffice but nowhere else) is actually a special character saying it can't be represented in unicode? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm

Comment: I never did get any of the answers on this page to work perfectly, but potong's solution got me the closest and the command provided some more exact detail on what was going wrong

Comment: Does not help to remove all non-ASCII characters. Only helps to remove specific one given in example.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -i 's/[^[:print:]]//' FILENAME
```

Also, this acts like dos2unix

Comment: Does not work. [:print:] is not the same as ASCII, e.g. `ü` is printable but not ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are having is the local.

if you want to use a collation range like that you need to change the character type and the collation type.

This fails as \x80 -> \xff are invalid in a utf-8 string.
note \u0080 != \x80 for utf8.

anyway to get this to work just do

```
LC_ALL=C sed -i 's/[\d128-\d255]//' FILENAME
```

this will override LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE for the one command and do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I came here trying this sed command `s/[\x00-\x1F]/ /g;`, which gave me the same error message.

in this case it simply suffices to remove the `\x00` from the collation, yielding `s/[\x01-\x1F]/ /g;`

Unfortunately it seems like all characters above and including `\x7F` and some others are disallowed, as can be seen with this short script:

```sh
for (( i=0; i<=255; i++ )); do 
    printf "== $i - \x$(echo "ibase=10;obase=16;$i" | bc) =="
    echo '' | sed -E "s/[\d$i-\d$((i+1))]]//g"
done
```

Note that the problem is only the use of those characters to specify a range. You can still list them all manually or per script. E.g. to come back to your example:

```sh
sed -i 's/[\d128-\d255]//' FILENAME
```

would become

```sh
c=; for (( i=128; i<255; i++ )); do c="$c\d$i"; done
sed -i 's/['"$c"']//' FILENAME
```

which would translate to:

```sh
sed -i 's/[\d128\d129\d130\d131\d132\d133\d134\d135\d136\d137\d138\d139\d140\d141\d142\d143\d144\d145\d146\d147\d148\d149\d150\d151\d152\d153\d154\d155\d156\d157\d158\d159\d160\d161\d162\d163\d164\d165\d166\d167\d168\d169\d170\d171\d172\d173\d174\d175\d176\d177\d178\d179\d180\d181\d182\d183\d184\d185\d186\d187\d188\d189\d190\d191\d192\d193\d194\d195\d196\d197\d198\d199\d200\d201\d202\d203\d204\d205\d206\d207\d208\d209\d210\d211\d212\d213\d214\d215\d216\d217\d218\d219\d220\d221\d222\d223\d224\d225\d226\d227\d228\d229\d230\d231\d232\d233\d234\d235\d236\d237\d238\d239\d240\d241\d242\d243\d244\d245\d246\d247\d248\d249\d250\d251\d252\d253\d254\d255]//' FILENAME
```

Comment: "_Unfortunately it seems like all characters above and including \x7F and some others are disallowed_". Thanks! That explained why I'm getting the `Invalid collation character` error.

Comment: Very helpful to identify that `\u0000` can't be used as part of a range as well.

Answer (score 1):

In this case there is a way to just skip non-ASCII chars, not bothering with removing.

```
LANG=C sed /someemailpattern/
```

See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=440419 and [Will sed (and others) corrupt non-ASCII files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670916/will-sed-and-others-corrupt-non-ascii-files).

Answer (score 0):

How about using `awk` for this. We setup the Field Separator to nothing. Then loop over each character. Use an `if loop` to check if it matches our `character class`. If it does we print it else we ignore it.

```
awk -v FS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /[A-Za-z,.@ ]/) printf $i}'
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "Chip,Dirkland,DrobæSphere Inc,cdirkland@hotmail.com,usa" | 
awk -v FS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /[A-Za-z,.@ ]/) printf $i}'
Chip,Dirkland,DrobSphere Inc,cdirkland@hotmail.com,usa
```

**Update:**

```
awk -v FS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /[A-Za-z,.@ ]/) printf $i; printf "\n"}' < datafile.csv > asciidata.csv
```

I have added printf "\n" after the loop to keep the lines separate.

Comment: Thanks Jaypal, how would this be modified if you wanted to process datafile.csv and output asciidata.csv?

Comment: If you only want e-mail address extracted from your input file then `awk` can do that in a breeze without any complex `regex`. Let me know how it works out.