# Trying to delete non-ASCII characters only

Tags: regex, linux, sed, tr

I am trying to manipulate a text file and remove non-ASCII characters from the text. I don't want to remove the line. I only want to remove the offending characters. I am trying to get the following expression to work:

`sed '/[\x80-\xFF]/d'`

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337936/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-csv) answer.

Comment: This thread might have the answer you are looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571601/skip-remove-non-ascii-character-with-sed

Comment: Your command will delete all lines containing non-ascii characters.  If that's not what you want, check the duplicate questions

Comment: I have tried two commands : 1) sed -E 's/[^[:print:]]//' <-- this should remove non printable characters. However, non printable stuff is still appearing. When I try to use sed -E 's/[\d128-\d255]//', I get a Invalid Collation error. Is there any other commands that somone can suggest to remove non-ascii characters only

Comment: There is decent perl example in the first comments link. If that is what you mean by "any other commands"...

Comment: Thanks Josh but I am looking to do it with Sed or maybe TR

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The suggested solutions may fail with specific version of sed, e.g. GNU sed 4.2.1.

Using `tr`:

```
tr -cd '[:print:]' < yourfile.txt
```

This will remove any characters not in `[\x20-\x7e]`.

If you want to keep e.g. line feeds, just add `\n`:

```
tr -cd '[:print:]\n' < yourfile.txt
```

If you really want to keep *all* ASCII characters (even the control codes):

```
tr -cd '[:print:][:cntrl:]' < yourfile.txt
```

This will remove any characters not in `[\x00-\x7f]`.

Comment: Hey speakr, is there a way to preserve the format of the text file. The tr command feeds everything onto a continuous line right?

Comment: @bosra: I added an example to preserve line feeds.

Comment: Man, if I could upvote this a few more times I would..Thanks

Comment: any idea why meld would still consider the fixed files as binary? btw, the result seems different from `tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176'` which worked with meld (at least with my files) [ref](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/how-remove-non-printable-ascii-characters-file-unix)

Comment: This question helped me a lot, but since I wanted to keep the \n and \t in the output file, I used the command below instead:

tr -cd '[:print:][/n/t]' < yourfile.txt > output.txt