# How to remove control characters from standard input, except tabs?

Tags: perl, bash

I want to remove control characters (like ^C, ^A, and so on) from a standard input and print it to standard output, using just basic bash, perl and some other linux tools.

What I do right now is

```
(something) | sed 's/[[:cntrl:]]//g' | (something else)
```

Which worked until now, but now I found out it removes tabulators too and I want to keep those.

So, is there something else, just working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modyfying second answer from [Skip/remove non-ascii character with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571601/skip-remove-non-ascii-character-with-sed) , I got this working sed script

```
sed 's/[^[:print:]\t]//'g
```

It seems to work (altough the "non-ascii" part is wrong, it does not remove any unicode).

For Unicode to work, you have to have the environment variables set up as `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and `LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"` (and exported).

Comment: it certainly does remove non-printable unicode, but will only expect unicode input if your local environment variables are set appropriately (e.g. `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`)

Answer (score 1):

You could just define the character class yourself based on the [definition of `[:cntrl:]`](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html):

```
sed 's/[\x00\-\x08\x10-\x1F\x7F]\{1,\}//g'
```

Comment: `sed: -e expression #1, char 35: Invalid collation character`

Comment: `echo $'a\tb'|sed 's/[\x00\-\x08\x10\-\x19\x7F]\{1,\}//g'` - the result is `ab`.

Comment: I think you got mixed up between hex and decimal! What about `\x0A` through `\x0F`?

Comment: Actually your link has it wrong too. It should read `[[:cntrl:]]  - [\x00-\x1F\x7F]`. I guess that's what confused you.

Comment: @Borodin Good catch.  I didn't even really pay attention to what the other site put.  See my edits.

Comment: @TimPote: That looks better. Also it should be `[:cntrl:]` instead of `[:ctrl:]`. I've fixed that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ssed`([super-sed](http://www.ososo.de/extreg/)) with perl-regex:

```
echo -e 'hello\tworld' | ssed 's/(?!\t)[[:cntrl:]]//g'
```

Comment: You can try `perl` with a perl regex `perl -pe 's/(?!\t)[[:cntrl:]]//g'`.