# Removing non-alphanumeric characters with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, replace

I am trying to validate some inputs to remove a set of characters. Only alphanumeric characters plus, period, underscore, hyphen are allowed. I've tested the regex expression `[^\w.-]` here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it matches what I want removed so I not sure why `sed` is returning the opposite. What am I missing?

My end goal is to input `"Â10.41.89.50 "` and get `"10.41.89.50`".

I've tried:

`echo "Â10.41.89.50 " | sed s/[^\w.-]//g` returns `Â...`

`echo "Â10.41.89.50 " | sed s/[\w.-]//g` and `echo "Â10.41.89.50 " | sed s/[\w^.-]//g` returns `Â10418950`

I attempted the answer found here [Skip/remove non-ascii character with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571601/skip-remove-non-ascii-character-with-sed) but nothing was removed.

Comment: Try adding the `-r` option to `sed` so it will recognize extended regular expressions.

Comment: `sed` doesn't understand the special character classes like `\w`.  Just use `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`.

Comment: neither `-r` nor using `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` works. Well `echo "Â10.41.89.50 " | sed s/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]//g` returned `Â` but `echo "Â10.41.89.50 " | sed s/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]//g` still returned `Â10.41.89.50`.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[tr](/questions/tagged/tr)'s `-c` (complement) flag may be an option

```
echo "Â10.41.89.50-._ " | tr -cd '[:alnum:]._-'
```

Comment: @AlexanderMills, @Herlon, While the `tr` incantation above is POSIX-compliant, I do not have MacOS handy to test

Comment: This answer works fine on macOS, it's just that the locale includes non-English letters in the `:alnum:` character class (as it should).  If you want to remove non-English characters, try this: `echo "Â10.41.89.50-._ /" | tr -cd '[a-zA-Z0-9]._-'`

Comment: @iruvar, I think you need to drop those extra brackets (the class is '[:alnum:]' not '[[:alnum:]]' and tr isn't sed/perl etc.) as otherwise your expression will allow those non-alphanumerics ('[', ']') through. I've just hit this

Comment: using `LANG=C tr -cd '...'` might be a good idea

Answer (score 28):

You might want to use the `[:alpha:]` class instead:

```
echo "Â10.41.89.50 " | sed "s/[[:alpha:].-]//g"
```

should work. If not, you might need to change your local settings.

On the other hand, if you only want to keep the digits, the hyphens and the period::

```
echo "Â10.41.89.50 " | sed "s/[^[:digit:].-]//g"
```

If your string is in a variable, you can use pure bash and [parameter expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for that:

```
$ dirty="Â10.41.89.50 "
$ clean=${dirty//[^[:digit:].-]/}
$ echo "$clean"
10.41.89.50
```

or

```
$ dirty="Â10.41.89.50 "
$ clean=${dirty//[[:alpha:]]/}
$ echo "$clean"
10.41.89.50
```

You can also have a look at `1_CR`'s answer.

Comment: @dw1: No, I don't think so. In the first example, we want to *remove all letters, periods and hyphens,* and that's what the command does (`sed` replaces these symbols by nothing). Last example is the same logic, but with Bash's parameter expansion.

Answer (score 15):

To remove all characters except of alphanumeric and "-" use this code:

```
echo "a b-1_2" | sed "s/[^[:alnum:]-]//g"
```

Answer (score 7):

Well sed won't support unicode characters. Use `perl` instead:

```
> s="Â10.41.89.50 "
> perl -pe 's/[^\w.-]+//g' <<< "$s"
10.41.89.50
```

Comment: @jthill: It didn't on my OSX (could be due to some locales).

Comment: So looks like sed on my OSX 10.6.8 doesn't have support for unicode but gnu-sed should have unicode support.

Comment: @gorideyourbike: Fair enough, feel free to use any of the other answers.

Comment: @anubhava shouldn't be locale, perl honors that.  I suppose Apple's got a backlevel sed, what's `sed --version` say?

Comment: @jthill: `sed --version` gives error: `sed: illegal option -- -`

Answer (score 2):

```
s/[^[:alnum:]+._-]//g
```

removes anything other than alphanumeric and ".+_-" characters.

```
echo "Â10.41.89.50 +-_" | sed s/[^[:alnum:]+._-]//g
Â10.41.89.50+-_
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation

Comment: @user3142695 This isn't a replacement for the manual. This answers the Q. man sed from there.  No tricks. No hocus pocus. There's no rocket science there.

Comment: nope, this will replace the first character of the input with nothing - ^ is the beginning of the string in sed

Answer (score 0):

```
<`[[:alnum:]_.@]`
```

This worked just fine for me. It preserved all of the characters I specified for my purposes.