# Extracting release number from Jira created bitbucket branch

Tags: bash, sed

I am using Jira to create a bitbucket branch for releases. As part of the build process I need to extract the release number from the branch name.

An earlier part of the build dumps the whole branch name to a text file. The problem I'm having is removing all the text before the build number.

An example branch name would be:

```
release/some-jira-ticket-343-X.X.X
```

Where X.X.X is the release number e.g. 1.11.1 (each of X could be any length integer).

My first thought was to literally just select the last 3 characters with sed, however as X could be any length this won't work.

Another post ([Removing non-alphanumeric characters with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007288/removing-non-alphanumeric-characters-with-sed)) suggesting using the sed alpha class. However this won't work as the jira ticket ID will have numbers in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use string operators:

```
var="release/some-jira-ticket-343-2.155.7"
echo ${var##*-}
```

print:

```
2.155.7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all characters up to last `-`:

```
$ sed 's/.*-//' <<< "release/some-jira-ticket-343-1.11.2"
1.11.2
```

or with `grep`, to output only digits and dots at the end of the line:

```
grep -o '[0-9.]*$'
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` solution,

```
$ awk -F- '{print $NF}' <<< "release/some-jira-ticket-343-1.11.1"
```

`grep` solution,

```
grep -oP '[0-9]-\K.*' <<< "release/some-jira-ticket-343-1.11.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk solution:

```
awk -F [-.] '{ print $5"."$6"."$7 }' <<< "release/some-jira-ticket-343-12.4.7"

12.4.7
```

Set the field delimiter to - and . and then extract the pieces of data we need.