# how to use sed delete Unicode in some range?

Tags: regex, unicode, sed

I want to remove Unicode in some range, e.g.:

`echo "abcＡＢＣ123" | sed 's/[\uff21-\uff3b]//g'`

expect `"abc123"`, but get:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 20: Invalid range end

or use:

`echo "abcＡＢＣ123" | sed 's/[Ａ-Ｚ]//g'`

get:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 14: Invalid collation character

Comment: See https://ideone.com/woqDKM. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571601/skip-remove-non-ascii-character-with-sed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode support in `sed` is not well defined. You may be better off using command line `perl`:

```
echo "abcＡＢＣ123" | perl -CS -pe 's/[\x{FF21}-\x{FF3B}]+//g'

abc123
```

It is important to use `-CS` flags here to be able to get correct UTF8 encodings for input/output/error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why `sed` is not working, but you can use `tr` instead

```
$ echo 'abcＡＢＣ123' | tr -d 'Ａ-Ｚ'
abc123
```

From `man tr`

> tr - translate or delete characters
>
> -d, --delete
>   delete characters in SET1, do not translate