# How to remove non-ascii chars using sed

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, non-ascii-characters

I want to remove non-ascii chars from some file. I have already tried these many regexs.

```
sed -e 's/[\d00-\d128]//g'  # not working

cat /bin/mkdir | sed -e 's/[\x00-\x7F]//g' >/tmp/aa
```

but this file contains some non-ascii chars.

```
[root@asssdsada ~]$ hexdump /tmp/aa |more
          00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 - 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F  0123456789ABCDEF

00000000  45 4C 46 B0 F0 73 38 C0 - C0 BC BC FF FF 61 61 61  ELF..s8......aaa
00000010  A0 A0 50 E5 74 64 50 57 - 50 57 50 57 D4 D4 51 E5  ..P.tdPWPWPW..Q.
00000020  74 64 6C 69 62 36 34 6C - 64 6C 69 6E 75 78 78 38  tdlib64ldlinuxx8
00000030  36 36 34 73 6F 32 47 4E - 55 42 C8 C0 80 70 69 42  664so2GNUB...piB
00000040  44 47 BA E3 92 43 45 D5 - EC 46 E4 DE D8 71 58 B9  DG...CE..F...qX.
00000050  8D F1 EA D3 EF 4B 86 FC - A9 DA 79 ED 63 B5 51 92  .....K....y.c.Q.
00000060  BA 6C FC D1 69 78 30 ED - 74 F1 73 95 CC 85 D2 46  .l..ix0.t.s....F
00000070  A5 B4 6C 67 DA 4A E9 9A - 4B 58 77 A4 37 80 C0 4F  ..lg.J..KXw.7..O
00000080  F3 E9 B2 77 65 97 74 F9 - A2 C0 F2 CC 4A 9C 58 A1  ...we.t.....J.X.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This doesn't seem to work with `sed`. Perhaps `tr` will do?

```
tr -d '\200-\377'
```

Or with the complement:

```
tr -cd '\000-\177'
```

Comment: @EladTabak: It should work. Can you produce an example where is does not work?

Comment: On macOS High Sierra, I get this error: `tr: Illegal byte sequence`.

Comment: @codeforester: I tested this with tr from GNU coreutils

Comment: tr -cd '\001-\177' removes the NULL character do, worth removing, many tools such as grep recognize input as binary if it contains nulls. Binary file (standard input) matches.

Answer (score 8):

Did you try

```
cat /bin/mkdir | tr -cd "[:print:]"
```

I think it solves the problem ?

If only text content interest you, you can also use

```
cat /bin/mkdir | strings
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you know what encoding the file is currently using? If so, you can use iconv to convert it. It's a utility to convert from one character encoding to another. So if the original file is in UTF-8 and you want to convert to ASCII you can use the following:

```
iconv -f utf8 -t ascii <inputfile>
```

The file command on the input file might tell you the current encoding.

Interestingly, there's a command called [enca](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enca) which will do its best to determine the character encoding being used if you know the language of the contents of the file.

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337936/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-csv) might be the answer.

Comment: I am working on linux system, which is having very limited pool of commands and 'iconv' is not available.

Comment: Looking at the output from hexdump, is this a binary file? (Guessing from ELF at the start) If so, what's the purpose of removing non-ascii characters? The binary will be corrupted.

Comment: it is just an example, friend.

Comment: Ah, cool. I've added a link to a related question which might solve your problems.

Comment: same is working fine with this perl command, But I need sed.
cat /bin/mkdir | perl -ne 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g;print $_;'

Comment: enca also not available on my machine.

% enca
enca: Command not found.

Comment: Rather than cat'ing the file, have you tried just passing it to sed as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions offered here did not work for me. Maybe my problem was different, but I needed to strip the ASCII colors and other characters from the otherwise pure ASCII text.

The following worked for me, however:

Stripping Escape Codes from ASCII Text

```bash
sed -E 's/\x1b\[[0-9]*;?[0-9]+m//g'
```

In context (BASH):

```bash
$ printf "\e[32;1mhello\e[0m\n"
hello

$ printf "\e[32;1mhello\e[0m\n" | cat -vet
^[[32;1mhello^[[0m$

$ printf "\e[32;1mhello\e[0m\n" | sed -E 's/\x1b\[[0-9]*;?[0-9]+m//g' | cat -vet
hello$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **sed -i** option, eg.

```
sed -i 's/[\d128-\d255]//g' MYFILE.txt
```

it will replace all non-ascii characters in the file.

Comment: For me at least -- running this on my file removed all lowercase ascii characters