# Removing all special characters from a string in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, tr, linux-mint

I have a lot of text in lowercase, only problem is, that there is a lot of special characters, which I want to remove it all with numbers too.

Next command it's not strong enough:

```
tr -cd '[alpha]\n '
```

In case of éćščž and some others it returns "?" But I want to remove all of them. Is there any stronger command?

I use linux mint 4.3.8(1)-release

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Giving a bit more context would maybe draw more helpful responses.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `tr` to print only the printable characters from a string like below. Just use the below command on your input file.

```
tr -cd "[:print:]\n" < file1
```

The flag `-d` is meant to the delete the character sets defined in the arguments on the input stream, and `-c` is for complementing those (invert what's provided). So without `-c` the command would delete all printable characters from the input stream and using it complements it by removing the **non-printable** characters. We also keep the newline character `\n` to preserve the line endings in the input file. Removing it would just produce the final output in one big line.

The `[:print:]` is just a [POSIX bracket expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) which is a combination of expressions `[:alnum:]`, `[:punct:]` and space.  The `[:alnum:]` is same as `[0-9A-Za-z]` and `[:punct:]` includes characters `!` `"` `#` `$` `%` `&` `'` `(` `)` `*` `+` `,` `-` `.` `/` `:` `;` `<` `=` `>` `?` `@` `[` `\` `]` `^` `_` `` ` `` `{` `|` `}` `~`

Comment: Unfortunately tr's character class [:print:] does not include all letters in each locale, e.g. ä in Finnish.

Comment: Not true about print being the same as alnum punc and space. I had a problem with characters messing up my terminal tr -dc "[:alnum:][:punct:] \n" fixed it but tr -dc "[:print:]\n" doesn't. So allnum, punc, space must be a subset of print.

Answer (score 4):

I am not exactly certain where the text is coming from in your question but lets just say that the "lot of text in lowercase" is in the file called `special.txt` you could do something like the following but focused more on the characters you want to keep:

```
cat special.txt | sed 's/[^a-z  A-Z]//g'
```

It is a bit like doing surgery with an axe though.

Another possible solution in the post [Remove non-ascii characters from ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3337960/171475)

If the above don't solve your question, please try to provide a bit more details and I might be able to provide a more actionable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add my bit to it. The code below will do a better job of getting rid of all characters as explained above and will replace them with space and preserve your newline character at the same time

```
    tr -s "[:punct:]" " "
```

From Manual Entry -s

> Squeeze multiple occurrences of the characters listed in the last operand (either string1 or string2) in the input into a single instance of the character. This occurs after all deletion and translation is completed.