# how to read a string with special charcters from one file to grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

what i'm trying is, reading all the strings from one file which also include special characters ie. ,/\'" etc.
and i'm doing cat of one file with grep above string to check occurrence but it's not working for some special strings.

**file1.txt**

```
Error:'abcd' not found; Try Again
Error:load() loading provider library version 3.5(r182) By <info@xyz.com>
Warning: Connection to group 'xyz-xyz'
```

**Filename.log**

```
2017-06-19 06:50:28 Error:'abcd' not found; Try Again
2017-06-19 06:50:28 Error:load() loading provider library version 3.5(r182) By <info@xyz.com>
2017-06-19 06:50:28 Warning: Connection to group 'xyz-xyz', peer '00.00.01.01:2200,00.00.01.01:2200,00.00.01.01:2200'
```

**inside script test1.sh**

```
while read STRING

do

cat Filename.log | grep -i -F "$STRING"

done<file1.txt
```

but it reads it as

```
grep -i -F 'Error:'\''abcd'\'' not found; Try Again'
```

And does not show any correct output.

So how can we ignore all the special characters inside this ?
Other strings without any special characters are working fine.

Thanks

Comment: special characters includes : ' () <> @ # $ ? ~

Comment: @anubhava, its a error log file , usually contains error messages
 such as above one "Error:'abcd' not found; Try Again" with date and time, other includes ip address and email id.
Only concern is special character inside string which i want to filter.

Comment: Try `grep -i -F file1.txt Filename.log` Question is very unclear. Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: Try to use `tr`: `cat Filename.log | tr "[:punct:]" " " | grep -i -F "$STRING"`

Comment: Find some inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337936/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-csv/3337960#3337960) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926999/removing-all-special-characters-in-bash)

Comment: `-F` doesn't interpret special characters... i.e `string=".*";grep -F "$string" `doesn't match everything.

Comment: i added some more information, hope it is better now

Comment: Works for me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr` and replace all punctuation characters if they are not needed

```
...
while read STRING
do
cat Filename.log | tr "[:punct:]" " " | grep -i -F "$STRING"
done<file1.txt
```

Or `| tr "\\\',/" " "` for another characters.

Comment: That's one approach, but again we'll have dependency on special characters we are passing on script.
can we have any way by which we can pass whole string under double quotes " ... "

Comment: You can replace `| tr "'" "\'"` and escape symbol `'  ` -
 `Error:\'abcd\' not found;`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after, using

> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>             Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f  is
>             specified by POSIX.)

```
$ cat file1.txt 
Error:'abcd' not found; Try Again
Error:load() loading provider library version 3.5(r182) By <info@xyz.com>
Warning: Connection to group 'xyz-xyz'

$ cat Filename.log 
2017-06-19 06:50:28 Error:'abcd' not found; Try Again
2017-06-19 06:50:28 Error:load() loading provider library version 3.5(r182) By <info@xyz.com>
2017-06-19 06:50:28 Warning: Connection to group 'xyz-xyz', peer '00.00.01.01:2200,00.00.01.01:2200,00.00.01.01:2200'

$ grep -i -f file1.txt Filename.log 
2017-06-19 06:50:28 Error:'abcd' not found; Try Again
2017-06-19 06:50:28 Error:load() loading provider library version 3.5(r182) By <info@xyz.com>
2017-06-19 06:50:28 Warning: Connection to group 'xyz-xyz', peer '00.00.01.01:2200,00.00.01.01:2200,00.00.01.01:2200'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fredrik it is working great for above case, but there is one case this is not working for me , if file1.txt string is starting with any special character..
ie. [Error]:'abcd' not founf;........

Comment: Again, works for me (tm), I'm using `grep (GNU grep) 2.20`