# mongoimport failed caused by some unknown character

Tags: mongodb

[unknown character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9qPI.png)
import failed caused by the character shown in the pic.

the json used in my proj is like this:

```
{"user_exam_id":1,"end_time":""}
```

(ff gone..., you need copy it to some editor.)

the error is:

```
Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character '\f' in string literal
```

I don't even known how to replace it or delete it. it looks like ^L in vim.
however, I tried to replace ^L and L with "", nothing happened...

Answer (score 0):

eventually solved~~~~~

the ff is just \x0c，which is not printable. we need to remove all unprintable characters from the json-file.

with sed, we can do it like this:

```
cat /tmp/testf.txt | sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g' > /tmp/an.txt
```

more information here. [replace unprintable characters with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337936/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-csv)