# remove non latin-1 characters in a text file

Tags: regex, sed, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have to replace all non latin-1 characters in the text of a large dataset file.
An example is like

```
LABEL   chini vich 妈妈媽媽 maama
LABEL   南支那海 南シナ海 shabadik ar h ngkhani shina saagar
LABEL   ॐ आप्यायन्तु ममाङ्गानि वाक्प्राणश्चक्षुः
```

where the 2nd column tabbed space owns the text to be found and replaced with a space.
The regex to find all latin-1 chars can be obtained using [character classes](https://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/regex/character-classes/) like

```
echo "chini vich 妈妈媽媽 maama" | sed "s/[[:alnum:]]*//g"
    妈妈媽
```

My aim is to *do exactly the opposite*:

```
echo "chini vich 妈妈媽媽 maama" | sed "s/(SOME REGEX)//g"
        chini vich maama
```

so replacing any occurence of a non latin-1 character sequence with a space `\s`.
I have tried to negate the character class `[:alnum:]` i.e. `[^A-Za-z0-9]` but it does not work.

NOTE
Since the 1st column will not contain any non latin-1 char, and it's alphanumeric, there should be no need to apply the regex to the 2nd column, so I think it's ok to apply it to the whole row so in `awk` it would be like `$(0)`.
For rows having non latin-1 char only like in the example below the regex will result in a empty 2nd column:

```
LABEL   chini vich maama
LABEL   shabadik ar h ngkhani shina saagar
LABEL
```

The similar question [Remove non-ASCII characters from CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337936/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-csv) is about removing non ASCI characters, here we are dealing with `ISO 8859` ASCII extension. For more info please refers to [What are the differences between ASCII, ISO 8859, and Unicode?](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahfr)

Comment: Maybe `[^[:alnum:]]*`?

Comment: yup! the inversion is ok, but I need to keep char spacing, but this would not work `sed "s/[^[:alnum:]]*/ /g"` because it will put spaces among all chars.

Comment: Okay, what if you try `sed -r "s/[^[:alnum:]]+/ /g"` (notice `+`)?

Comment: @revo `sed -r "s/[^[:alnum:]]+/ /g"` works!. When on `macos` the `-r` options (aka regex extended) is `-E` so it would be `echo "chini vich 妈妈媽媽 maama" | sed -E "s/[^[:alnum:]]+/ /g"`. Thank you.