# How to remove emojis from an xml node with command line

Tags: linux, xml, shell, sed

i want to remove emojis from XML files. A typical example string could be something like:

```
input: <UserName>JANE - MARIE &#55357;&#56628➡️</UserName>.
```

I want to have only:

```
OUTPUT : <UserName>JANE - MARIE</UserName>.
```

I tried to use **sed** but im not good with regular expression , can anyone help me , or suggerd me another function ?

THANKS

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question(which is highly encouraged on SO), thank you(not my downvote btw).

Comment: @Amine Al Arbi - You say you _want to remove emojis_ - why did you also remove a space then in your example?

Comment: Do you really have and want to handle malformed HTML character references without `;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to remove non-ASCII characters. This depends if you accept the Name with Unicode (e.g. names with á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ etc). In case this simple approach ([remove non-ascii characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337936/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-csv)) is sufficient with your requirement:

```sh
LANG=C sed -i 's/[\d128-\d255]//g' <FILENAME>
```

Tested on my side:

```sh
$ LANG=C sed -i 's/[\d128-\d255]//g' /tmp/x.txt
$ cat /tmp/x.txt
<UserName>JANE - MARIE &#55357;&#56628</UserName>.
```