# grep: filter out text containing ONLY specific characters

Tags: linux

I have a file containing filenames that look like this
    "aaa.ext"
    "abc"
    "a1a.ext"
    "béa"
    "pàt"
    "ff#!"
    "toto & #128;.pdf"
    "..."

I need to extract the lines that contain standard English Alphanumerals (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _ and .) AND other characters

Concerning the above example the output should be like
    béa (contains é instead of e)
    pàt (contains à instead of a)
    "ff#!"
    "toto & #128;.pdf"

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 grep '[A-Za-z0-9_.]' yourFile |
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 grep '[^A-Za-z0-9_.]'
```

which can also be written as

```
(export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8; grep -P '[\w.]' yourFile | grep -P '[^\w.]')
```

`LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` ensures that `A-Z` only matches standard english letters and not letters like `é`.

**Note:** In Unicode `é` can be encoded as either the real `é` or an `e` combined with a `´`. If your file contains the following two lines (without comments)

```
é # single character
é # combination of "e" and "´"
```

then the command from above will return

```
é # combination of "e" and "´"
```

The problem is a bit exotic and shouldn't cause much trouble.

Comment: Hi Socowi +1 for the quick response. The suggested command highlights the special characters however it does not seep to exclude the lines which don't contain any

Comment: @BNT Strange... I tested both commands for your example and got the desired results. Can you make another example in which a line without special characters is accepted?

Comment: here are a few more examples<BR>
12 - Mémo.pdf<br>
2016-04-25 &#4363;&#4457;&#4370;&#4462; 7.59.12.jpg<br>
20161109133127734.pdf<br>
~9963007Opoto.pdf<br>
In the above example; lines 2 and 4 should be retrieved, 1 and 3 should not<br>
Thanks again

Comment: @BNT Thanks for the additional example. For me the command accepts line 1, 2, and 4, which seems fine. Why should `12 - Mémo.pdf` be rejected? It contains the standard letters `12Mmo.pdf` *and* the other characters `-é` (note: space is also an "other character"). What is accepted on your system?

Comment: thanks for your feedback. my aim is to remove all non english chars from the filenames as they will be used on a wide variety of systems. The only acceptable characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _ - and . all others should be sorted out

Comment: @BNT Um, that's a completley different question ([this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3264915/6770384) may be of interest to you). Please close this question and ask a new one.

Comment: I might have explained my request in a wrong way. The requirement is that in the list of filenames contained in a text file, I need to extract the lines containing characters that are not within the English Alphanumeric set + the _ (underscore), the - (dash) and the . (dot). The answer you mentioned includes all ASCII so does not limit to only alphanumeric...